# Ctools rebuild form after modal-form submit

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I have a form with a table that displays a number of rows (each row contains user info). On form submit I edit all the users that are displayed in the table. Above the table I render a ctools link "Add user". This opens a modal dialog containing a form. After form submit I'm adding a row to the user table with this code:

```
$output[] = ajax_command_after('.managers-table tr:last', '<tr>my data</tr>');
```

This works fine, if I look into my DOM, the table contains that row. 
But here is the tricky part, how do I rebuild my "table-form"? Because when I submit my form, drupal doesn't know a row is added to the table, he just ignores the added row... How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `ctools_ajax_command_redirect()` to the same page perhaps?

Comment: This isn't a solution, because the table contains data that the user can edit. If I perform a redirect al the changes are lost...

Comment: A custom ajax command is probably your best course of action in that case

Comment: I want to use $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; But how can I get my form state of the table form in my ctools modal form?

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head - it will likely involve using [`form_get_cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_get_cache/7) to get the form state, then you'll need to alter it and invoke some JS on the front end to force the first form to rebuild itself

Comment: Clive, i've been searching on this problem for hours. Any idea how I can solve this? I tried your form_get_cache approach, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: With your current method you'll need to manually alter the form cache (as the form in the popup is not connected to the other in any meaningful way). The other way would be to move the link _inside_ the form (perhaps convert to a button), and use something similar to the code [here](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-using-ctools-modal-frames-and-field-collection-forms-create-better-user-experience). That will enable you to load the elements for your popup form as part of the original form, so you have access to the `$form_state` etc

Comment: @Clive seems [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135677/) is a duplicate of question above - OP there says you answered his issue here. Could you maybe post an answer and mark duplicate?